# não permitir que quando arrastar o dialog ele saia da area util da pagina

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

Quando eu arrasto o dialog para as extremidades da página, bottom ou right ele estoura a tela, como se ficasse fora do html, como posso fazer para impedir que ele ultrapasse as extremidades da página? coloquei o `overflow: hidden;` mas ele não impede

Comment: overflow:hidden na verdade vai esconder o elemento que ultrapassar o tamanho do pai.

Comment: pode postar os codigos?